# Time difference bash script

Tags: linux, bash, date-formatting

I am trying to make a bash script that will calculate the time difference between the users' first logon and the users most recent logon. Any help is appreciated :)

This is what I have so far:

```
read -p "Enter a user ID: " ID
echo "You entered the following ID(s): $ID"

#/bin/egrep -i "^$ID" /etc/passwd

echo -n "The users real name is: "
/bin/grep "^$ID" /etc/passwd | cut -f5 -d :

echo -n "$ID's first login time is: "
l1=`last "$ID" | tail -n 1`


echo -n "$ID's last login time is: "
l2=`last "$ID" | head -n 1`

echo $l1
echo $l2

echo -n "The time difference is $(l1-l2) "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based off the assumption you want to provide a username and not an ID.

Firstly, you want to perform your captures correctly

```
l1=$(last "$ID" | tail -n 1)
l2=$(last "$ID" | head -n 1)
```

in my instance left

```
l1="wtmp begins Sun Nov  9 07:32:12 2014"
l2="graham   pts/11       :0               Sat Nov 29 22:13   still logged in"
```

which is no good since we need ***only*** dates

So let's fix that. Here's some hacky parsing to get only times:

```
l1=$(last -RF | grep $ID | tail -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6)
l2=$(last -RF "$ID" | head -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6)
```

I grep for l1 because last leaves the last logged in, but for consistency, I just grab the last row. `last -RF` removes the host (`-R`), since we're not interested and makes the time a bit nicer (`-F`). `tr` trims all additional spaces and cut, delimited by a blank, grabs the date.

We want to compute the time between, so let's change both to datetime strings and subtract:

```
a=$(date -ud "$l2" +"%s") 
b=$(date -ud "$l1" +"%s")

d=$(( a-b ))
```

Finally let's print

```
echo "$ID's last login time is: $l1"
echo "$ID's first login time is: $l2"
echo "The time difference is $d seconds"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script seems to contain a number of errors.

> /bin/grep "^$ID" /etc/passwd | cut -f5 -d :

This matches the `/etc/passwd` file at the start (`^`) for the uid, AFAIK, the passwd file always starts with the username, not the uid.
Perhaps you are confused about what a user id means; in UNIX, a user id always refers to the numerical ID every user has; a username refers to the loginname that you type when you login.

In any case, using `getent` is a more reliable method; we could grep for `:$uid:`, but that might break if a group id is the same as a user id (among other scenarios). `getent` will also work with *both* a user id, and a user name.

Also, using `/bin/grep` is almost always a bad idea; lookups in `$PATH` are almost always better (so just use `grep`).

```
l1=`last "$ID" | tail -n 1`
```

`last` expects a username, not a user id; perhaps there is a flavour that also accepts a uid (?); in any case, using the username is more reliable.

> echo -n "The time difference is $(l1-l2)"

The dates from `last` are in a string format (`Sat Nov  1 00:39`); you can't just subtract those as integers, you first need to parse them with `date`.

Here is what a working version might look like; I've also made some other (minor) improvements that could be useful for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Keep asking for the uid until *something* is entered
while :; do
    read -p "Enter a user ID: " uid
    [ -n "$uid" ] && break
done

# Get line from /etc/passwd
passwd=$(getent passwd "$uid")

# Exit code was non-zero; the uid is unknown
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "User id '$uid' is unknown"
    exit 1
fi

# Get data from passwd
username=$(echo "$passwd" | cut -d: -f1)
realname=$(echo "$passwd" | cut -d: -f5)


# Get info from last, strip last 2 lines since they're not useful for us. Use
# ISO format so that date can parse them
lastlog=$(last --time-format iso "$username" | head -n-2)

# Get first & last line; we only need the date
last_login=$(echo "$lastlog" | head -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
first_login=$(echo "$lastlog" | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)

# Parse dates with date, output time in seconds since 1-1-1970 ('epoch')
diff=$(( $(date --date "$last_login" +%s) - $(date --date "$first_login" +%s) ))

# Format the date
diff_fmt=$(date --date @$diff +'%d days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds')

# Output info
echo "Found user $username ($realname) for userid $uid"
echo "First recorded login: $first_login"
echo "Last recorded login: $last_login"
echo "Difference: $diff_fmt (total of $diff seconds)"
```

Unfortunately, this will only work on Linux systems; making work on *all* UNIX flavours required a bit more work (shell scripting is often difficult to do portable)

Example output:

```
[~]% sh test.sh
Enter a user ID: 1001
Found user martin (Martin Tournoij) for userid 1001
First recorded login: 2014-11-01T00:13:28+0100
Last recorded login: 2014-11-30T06:08:54+0100
Difference: 30 days 06 hours 55 minutes 26 seconds (total of 2526926 seconds)
```

Comment: Much more comprehensive than mine. I'm not sure why I'm only now seeing this although you posted before me.

Comment: @DylanMadisetti Thanks :-) I posted it ~40 minutes ago, but thought it could be better/more comprehensive so I deleted my post. I made my improvements, and undeleted it just after you posted your answer :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to break the news to you, but your code will only work on Linux — it is not remotely portable.  The `getent` command is specific to Linux (not available on Mac OS X, for example).  The `last --time-iso` option is only available with GNU's `last` (not available on Mac OS X, for example).  All the major `date` options you're using are not directly available except with GNU's `date` command.  While the GNU code can be installed on any Unix-like system, the code won't work out of the box on most non-Linux systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks; doing this sort of thing platform-specific is difficult to do cleanly; FreeBSD, for example, has it's own extensions to `date` to do this, which are not compatible with GNU `date`, and `getent` is not Linux specific, I know that at least FreeBSD, NetBSD, and Solaris have it, but apparently not OSX... In any case, I assumed this question was about Linux... (I adjusted the compatibility remark).